# Error in Generating Java Code from StarUML

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram, staruml

I get an following Error when I try to generate the Java Code from StarUML class diagram

**Java Profile has not been included. 
Generate the code after including the Profile to the project. 
(Check the "generate......)**

I was following the below steps

*Tools --> Java --> Generate Code*

What is the missed step of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Menu -> 
"Tools" -> 
"Options.." ->
Select "Java" as "Option Category:" -> 
Tick "Generate codes even when there is no profile" as "Option Item:" -> 
Click "Ok"
```

It "Specifies whether to generate codes even when Java profile is not loaded in the project (not recommended)."

Now it is possible to generate java code.

Answer (score 0):

Menu -
Model -> profile
add language (like java ) to included profile .
done.